# How do I Escape Foreign Characters using Regex or StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, ascii

I have the following method to clean up strings:

```
public static String UseStringBuilderWithHashSet(string strIn)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<char>("?&^$#@!()+-,:;<>’\'-_*");
        // specify capacity of StringBuilder to avoid resizing
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strIn.Length);
        foreach (char x in strIn.Where(c => !hashSet.Contains(c)))
        {
            sb.Append(x);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

However, strings such as `[MV] REOL   ちるちる  ChiruChiru` or `[MV] REOL   ヒビカセ  Hibikase` do not get cleaned up.

How can I modify my method so it can turn one of the above strings into for example:
`[MV] REOL ChiruChiru`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to solve this exhaustively by filtering out everything you don't want. This is not optimal as their are 100,000+ possible characters.

You may find better results if you only accept what you do want.

```
public static string CleanInput(string input)
{
    //a-zA-Z allows any English alphabet character upper or lower case
    //\[ and \] allows []
    //\s allows whitespace
    var regex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z\[\]\s]");
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    foreach(char c in input){
        if(regex.IsMatch(c.ToString())){
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }
    string output = stringBuilder.ToString();
    //\s+ will match on any duplicate spaces and replace it with
    //a single space.
    return Regex.Replace(output , @"\s+", " ");
}
```

Comment: Good point, I did not think about it that way. Thank you for your help.